# Find an example of an inner product space $ V \ $ and a linear transformation $ \ T: V \to V \ $ with Eigen value

Tags: functional-analysis

Find an example of an inner product space $ V \ $ and a linear transformation $ \ T: V \to V \ $ with eigenvalue $ \ \lambda \in Eig(T) \ $ such that $ \ \lambda^* \notin Eig(T^*) \ $ .

**Answer:** I know that if the Linear transformation $ \ T \ $ is not normal , then $ \lambda^*  \notin Eig(T^*) $ .

But I can find an specific example.

Is there any help ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think being normal is relevant. Note that $(T - \lambda I)^* = T^* - \overline{\lambda} I$, and if $T^* - \overline{\lambda} I$ has an inverse $U$, then
$$(T - \lambda I) U^* = (U (T - \lambda I)^*)^* = I$$
and similarly for $U^*(T - \lambda I)$. Therefore, if $\overline{\lambda}$ is not an eigenvalue for $T^*$, then $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue for $T$.

Comment: will the space of hermitian matrices  work ?